# UIPIckerview strange display behaviour

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have an app written a few years ago using UIPickerView and had been working until now.

It doesn't display properly for iOS 16. So I thought I'd use Xcode to submit another build with the latest libraries etc but it still doesn't work!

I've attached the screenshots, you can see from the first one it should be "17 10 00" but it's showing "... ... ..." (but you can see "18 11 01").

[image]

So I select "18 11 01" but it shows "... 11 ..." (but now you can see "17 10 ..." above it).

[image]

There's no fixed pattern as to which numbers are displayed. All seem random.

I've made the picker quite big (like in this case) and it still doesn't display properly, so it's not a matter of the font size being too big for the display field.

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

The numbers are selected correctly and displays correctly in a text label.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: This really does look like label truncation where the test doesn’t fit, despite your claim that’s not it. The digit “1” is narrower than other digits which may explain why some values appear correct. Are you reducing the width of the columns or the picker from their defaults? The text metrics perhaps changed slightly in iOS 16 and your custom sizes are now a bit too small.

Comment: You're RIGHT! I found the code where the column width was set and lo and behold, once I changed the value of the width the numbers appear again!
And then I put in a "pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int" to size the font size rather than leaving it to default, and the problem is solved!
Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: @GeoffHackworth, Bevan:  You might want to take a look at this discussion about questions being answered in the comments - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat :)

Comment: @Bevan I rolled back your last update since there's no need to edit your question pointing out your answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got an email saying my question wasn’t clear (“needs details and clarity”) so I felt I was kinda doing the wrong thing and I didn’t want to offend anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the code where the column width was set and lo and behold, once I changed the value of the width the numbers appear correctly again! And then I put in a "pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int" to set the font size to a fixed value rather than leaving it to default, and the problem is solved!